# issue with Yii 2 framework

Tags: php, yii2, frameworks

I was trying to make a blog with YII2,  my framework is confusing to call data from database.

For example when I call "username" from "user" table,

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
   'user.fullname',     --->> Yii2 is thinking that this is a category and not a user table
        'title',
        'description',
        'content:html',
        'count_view',
        'status',
        'created_at',
    ],
]) ?>
```

I am getting this error:  -->>  unknown property: app\models\Category::fullname

please could you help me to solve this issue, where I did make a mistake?

and here is my post model contains:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "post".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $description
 * @property string $content
 * @property integer $count_view
 * @property string $status
 * @property string $created_at
 *
 * @property User $user
 * @property TagAssign[] $tagAssigns
 */
class Post extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'post';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id', 'count_view','category_id'], 'integer'],
            [['content', 'status'], 'string'],
            [['created_at'], 'safe'],
            [['count_view'], 'default','value'=>0],
            [['user_id'], 'default','value'=>Yii::$app->user->id],
            [['title', 'description'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'content' => 'Content',
            'category' => 'Category',
            'count_view' => 'Count View',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTagAssigns()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TagAssign::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

and here user Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $fullname
 * @property string $status
 * @property string $role
 * @property string $created_At
 *
 * @property Post[] $posts
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
public $current_password;
public $new_password;
public $confirm_password;
public $authKey;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['status', 'role'], 'string'],
            [['created_At'], 'safe'],
            [['username', 'password', 'fullname'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
          'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'fullname' => 'fullname',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'role' => 'Role',
            'created_At' => 'Created  At',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token,$type=null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['access_token'=>$token]);
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey == $authKey;
    }
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username'=>$username]);
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        if(Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password,$this->password))
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: did you try renaming your column into `user_fullname` both in the database and your widget?

Comment: `Category` and `user` Model? Check relation name and attribute name.

Comment: What's your `$model` contain?

Comment: yes, it is not working

Comment: this is my model---> public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'content' => 'Content',
            'category' => 'Category',
            'count_view' => 'Count View',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
        ];
    }

Comment: and `User` model?

Comment: no, it is post model, but I also written post model

Comment: `public function getUser() {return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']); }` this relation with category model not with post model. There is `Post` model instead of  `Category `.

Comment: I guess you assigned wrong foreign key in db or manually created these relations of post model.

Comment: thank you Insane Skull, you got my error and I fixed it, thank you guys a lot

Comment: insane skull, I need your help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547084/yii2-grid-filtering-is-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this in **Post** model.

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);   
}

public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```